# Matching a value upto 8 decimal places

Tags: java, eclipse, math

I have a value/rate. I need it to match to 8 decimal places.

I don't want to use Regex.

Is there any other way to do it?

I tried finding a lot online but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Sample input 65.2341234567

I just need to compare it to a value upto 8 decimal places. i.e. 64.23412345 .

Comment: Could you paste sample input and expected output

Comment: dont see the reason of downvote. The question is pretty clear?

Comment: Is rounding involved in the comparison? For example if you "compare up to 1 decimal place" and the value is 1.29999, would that match 1.3 or 1.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Compare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("65.2341234567").setScale(8, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
        BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("65.234123456799").setScale(8, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);

        System.out.println( "equals " + bd1.equals(bd2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the unpredictable machine precision you won't be always able to compare in this range of precision with standard data types.

I think it would be wiser to compare in a range with an epsilon value that marks the "lost" precision.

value < value-epsilon 
and
value > value+epsilon

let there be epsilon a small enough value like 0.002

as example.

I hope this helps.